# How do I set the total submissions limit when I create a node?

Tags: 8, webforms

I'm using "Webform Node" module to create event registrations.

Now I can set the total submissions limit of event in **Structure> Webforms> my webform type**

and when I create a webform node, there is no setting option:

[image]

---

Because every event has different submissions limit, I want to set the limit when I create the webform node, instead of in the webform type, how can I do it? thank you so much!

Comment: That sounds like something the module doesn't provide.  You may need to make a custom module to handle the submission limit on a per-node basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Go to the Webform's settings
  (/admin/structure/webform/manage/contact/settings)
- Scroll to 'Submission Limits'
- Set 'Total submissions limit per entity' or 'Per
  user submission limit per entity'

I think the labeling and additional help text could help better define this features.  Feel free to create a ticket in the Webform module's issue queue